# Why is it allowed to modify a constant using a pointer in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I was wondering why it is allowed to modify a constant using a pointer?

```
int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
  const int my_const = 9;
  int *ptr = &my_const;
  *ptr += 10;
  printf("%d", my_const);
  return 0;
}
```

This prints **19** without any error.
Is this a compiler specific behavior? (I am running *gcc 4.7* on Windows)

Thanks...

Comment: It's not allowed. Your program breaks the rules of the language. Pay attention to the diagnostic messages emitted by the compiler

Comment: Curious, what did you expect the code to be required to do?  Did you expect the code was required to stop and report a  message?

Comment: Hi M.M, I actually ran the code. There was only a warning to use a constant integer pointer instead of the regular one.

Comment: Hi chux, I was expecting some kind of runtime error since I was modifying a constant.